# Elastic Transcoder trimming time - accuracy problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I'm trying to encode and trim a video to an *exact* in and out point but I've noticed that the output is lacking some precision.

For example, I know that my clip should start at `1.61s` with a duration of `2.32s` so I configure the pipeline job like so:

```js
{
    PipelineId: ___,
    Input: {
        Key: ___,
        FrameRate: 'auto',
        Resolution: 'auto',
        AspectRatio: 'auto',
        Interlaced: 'auto',
        Container: 'auto',
        TimeSpan: { 
            StartTime: '00:00:01.610', 
            Duration: '00:00:02.320' 
        }
    },
    Outputs: [{
        Key: ___,
        PresetId: ___,
    }]
}
```

The output, though, has a duration of `2.36s` and – it's hard to confirm – but the in-point seems to be a few frames early.

The input video is 100fps so when giving timing information to the precision of 1/100th second, I expect the precision of the in- and outpoints to not differ much. (Maybe one frame depending on the definition of where the time is in relation to the frame.)

I suspect it might be trimming from the nearest I-frame instead of the nearest *actual* frame. If so, is there any way to force it to trim at the intended positions?

For context, the videos are meant to be synced to other external data, which is why the in-point and duration is crucial to get correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I'm pretty sure what's going wrong. I generated a test video with burned-in time code and exported it in various formats. They were all trimmed correctly. So it isn't a *general* issue in Elastic Beanstalk since it works fine for those files.

I then encoded the original video without cropping and I could see that the output file was considerably shorter. The original length was `6.90s`, but the output was `6.12s`. I then converted the same file using FFMPEG locally and its output was `6.08s`.

So it appears that the original video was encoded in a way that's (partly) incompatible with both Elastic Transcoder and FFMPEG. The original video is encoded using an ancient codec - Microsoft Video 1 - using an unknown encoder. I assume some property of it simply isn't read correctly any longer by modern tools.